# Show a notification count in the title

Tags: feature-request, notifications

At present, the Ask Ubuntu questions page changes the title to add a count of questions with new activity since the page was loaded. I think it'd be a lot more, if not just as much, useful to show a count of notifications as well, or instead. Perhaps it will be make the title too cluttered, and so could be limited to other pages. Or only page-specific changes, which might be too complex.

Comment: still puzzled why the new questions activity bit is needed in the title...

Comment: @Wilf, I don't know, I am pretty recent member (as far as activity is concerned). At any rate, that feature sort of opens the door to similar ones, I think. It is occasionally useful.